# ¿Es posible hacer una Pila con JList?

Tags: java, pilas

Mi programa debe hacer la función de una pila (Stack). Lo hice con una interfaz, metí use un *texfield* y un botón para meter los datos que se ingresaran a la pila (JList) y si se ingresan en el JList el problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que se apilen.

Ejemplo: Yo debo ingresar `10, 20, 30, 40 y 50`, entonces en el JList deben aparecer así:

```
50 
40
30
20
10
```

Les dejo mi código y una imagen de la interfaz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package epila;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Pilas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultListModel Numeros  = new DefaultListModel();    

    public Pilas() {
        setTitle("Programa de Pila ");
        setResizable(false);
        initComponents();
        jLabel4.setVisible(false);
        jLabel1.setVisible(false);
        jLabel2.setVisible(false);
        Pila.setVisible(false); //Para no mostrar luego los datos en la pila.
        Pila.setSelectionBackground(Color.yellow); /*Hace que algun elemento que
        se seleccione del JList cambie al color indicado.*/
        Pila.setToolTipText("Pila");
    }
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Pilas pilita = new Pilas();
        String dato;
        int Dato, numeros=0;
        try{
            Dato = Integer.parseInt(Tex1.getText()); 
            Numeros.addElement(Dato);
            Pila.setModel(Numeros);
            Tex1.setText(null);
            jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Numeros.getSize()));
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes ingresar un valor");
        }
    }                                        
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Numeros.removeAllElements();
        jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Numeros.getSize()));
    }                                        
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(Numeros.getSize()>0){
        int n = Pila.getSelectedIndex();
        Numeros.removeElementAt(n);
        Pila.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
        jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Numeros.getSize()));
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jLabel4.setVisible(true);
        jLabel1.setVisible(true);
        jLabel2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: En vez de `TextField` yo usaría [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). Y pondría nombres de métodos más representativos. Tú lo que quieres es una pila `LIFO` asi que no metas los nuevos elementos al final si no al principio de la lista

Comment: Para hacer un Pila LIFO

Comment: Como te explico el programa ya esta a un 90 % 
solo necesito saber como ordenar los numeros  en forma de pila

Comment: lo importante esta en el  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

Comment: pues es donde ingreso los datos al  TextField y el boton los manda al jList

Comment: En java las variables es mejor ponerlas en minúsculas por convenio, el `addElement` añade los elementos al final de la lista, a lo mejor el método que pinta la lista, los pinta como si fuera una cola en vez de pila. Si no quieres hacer muchos cambios deberías meter los elemento siempre al comienzo de la lista ´add(int index (0), E element)´

Answer (score 1):

[image: si se puede]

dejo el archivo:
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package pilagrafica;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;

/**
 *
 * @author Harlericho
 */
public class Pila {

Pila cima;
int tope;
String dato;
Pila siguiente;

public Pila() {
    cima = null;
    tope = 0;
}

public Pila(String elemento) {
    dato = elemento;
    siguiente = null;

}

public void insertarPila(String ele) {
    Pila insertar = new Pila(ele);
    insertar.siguiente = cima;
    cima = insertar;
    tope++;
}

public String eliminarPila() {
    String aux = cima.dato;
    cima = cima.siguiente;
    tope--;
    return aux;
}

public boolean vaciaPila() {
    return cima == null;
}

public int topePila() {
    return tope;
}

public void inprimirPila() {
    Pila aux = cima;
    String cadena = "";
    while (aux != null) {
        cadena = cadena + aux.dato + "\n";

        aux = aux.siguiente;
    }
    System.out.println("" + cadena);
}
}
```

---------------------/*
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package pilagrafica;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Harlericho
 */
public class PilaGraf extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Pila pili = new Pila();

/**
 * Creates new form PilaGraf
 */
public PilaGraf() {
    initComponents();

}

public void mostrarPila() {
    DefaultListModel modelo = new DefaultListModel();
    Pila aux = pili.cima;
    String cadena = "";
    while (aux != null) {
        cadena =  aux.dato + "\n";
        modelo.addElement(cadena);
        aux = aux.siguiente;
    }
    jLiPila.setModel(modelo);

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    jcMousePanel1 = new jcMousePanel.jcMousePanel();
    jtxtTexto = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jLiPila = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Pila");

    jcMousePanel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/Playing_God.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jcMousePanel1.setVisibleLogo(false);

    jLabel1.setText("Datos a la Pila:");

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jLiPila);

    jButton1.setText("Añadir");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Tope");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Borrar");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jcMousePanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jcMousePanel1);
    jcMousePanel1.setLayout(jcMousePanel1Layout);
    jcMousePanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(66, 66, 66)
            .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jtxtTexto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                    .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap(58, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jcMousePanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(71, 71, 71)
            .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jtxtTexto))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(jcMousePanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)))
            .addContainerGap(113, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jcMousePanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 378, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jcMousePanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 345, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    pili.insertarPila(jtxtTexto.getText());
    mostrarPila();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tope es: "+pili.topePila());
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton3ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    pili.eliminarPila();
    mostrarPila();
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton3ActionPerformed

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PilaGraf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PilaGraf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PilaGraf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PilaGraf.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PilaGraf().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JList<String> jLiPila;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private jcMousePanel.jcMousePanel jcMousePanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jtxtTexto;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) no permite agregar o remover elementos directamente. En lugar de ello, lo que posee es un [`ListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) interno que contiene la lista de elementos que posee. Dependiendo de la implementación de `ListModel` a escoger, por ejemplo [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) te permite agregar los elementos dinámicamente allí. Lo que puedes hacer es que tu instancia de `DefaultListModel` la trates como a una pila.

Ejemplo:

```
DefaultListModel<Integer> pila = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<Integer> lista = new JList(pila);

//...

public void push(Integer numero) {
    pila.addElement(numero);
}

public void pop() {
    if (!pila.isEmpty()) {
        pila.removeElementAt(pila.size() - 1);
    }
}
```